# How to expire s3 objects when another object is added to the same folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a folder on s3 that should only contain one object at a time. I want to use Amazon's Lifecycle Management to expire/delete the older object when something else is uploaded to the folder. I'm not seeing that functionality in the docs though. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the object lifecycle rules based on number of object - count isn't possible.

These are the following alternatives you may try

1) manually running a CRON job with AWS script like boto to see the number of files in each folder and then deleting the older one

2) make your naming convention policy the same i.e. Ensure always you upload the file with the same name so the older one gets overwritten and you don't have to delete

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to apply the rule to handle some edge cases, but I'll go with the naming convention one.